# How to replace the Nth occurence of a pattern to add extra terms in vim

Tags: regex, vim, replace

I have:

```
elif paramo == 3:
    fold_path = [Pk_Path+"ns_up", Pk_Path+"ns_up2", Pk_Path+"fid", Pk_Path+"ns_dw", Pk_Path+"ns_dw2"]
    CC_path = ["C_ns_up", "C_ns_up2", "C_fid", "C_ns_dw", "C_ns_dw2"]
```

and I would like to get:

```
elif paramo == 3:
    fold_path = [Pk_Path+"ns_up", Pk_Path+"ns_up2", Pk_Path+"ns_up3", Pk_Path+"fid", Pk_Path+"ns_dw", Pk_Path+"ns_dw2", Pk_Path+"ns_dw3"]
    CC_path = ["C_ns_up", "C_ns_up2", "C_ns_up3", "C_fid", "C_ns_dw", "C_ns_dw2", "C_ns_dw3"]
```

For the first line I can add an extra `Pk_Path+"ns_up3"` after `Pk_Path+"ns_up2"` by doing:

```
:'<,'>s/, Pk_Path+\(.\{-}\)_up2"/, Pk_Path+\1_up2", Pk_Path+\1_up3"/g
```

and it insertions "`ns_up3`":

```
elif paramo == 3:
    fold_path = [Pk_Path+"ns_up, "Pk_Path+"ns_up2", Pk_Path+"ns_up3", Pk_Path+"fid", Pk_Path+"ns_dw", Pk_Path+"ns_dw2"]
    CC_path = ["C_ns_up", "C_ns_up2", "C_fid", "C_ns_dw", "C_ns_dw2"]
```

But for the other term `Pk_Path+"ns_dw3"`, I tried to do:

```
:'<,'>s/, Pk_Path+\(.\{-}\)_dw2"/Pk_Path+\1_dw2", Pk_Path+\1_dw3"/g
```

but this produced the wrong results:

```
elif paramo == 3:
    fold_path = [Pk_Path+"ns_up"Pk_Path+"ns_up2"Pk_Path+"ns_up3", Pk_Path+"fid", Pk_Path+"ns_dw", Pk_Path+"ns_dw2", Pk_Path+"ns_up3", Pk_Path+"fid", Pk_Path+"ns_dw", Pk_Path+"ns_dw3"]
    CC_path = ["C_ns_up", "C_ns_up2", "C_fid", "C_ns_dw", "C_ns_dw2"]
```

I don't know how to explicitly indicate that I want to insert `Pk_Path+"ns_dw3"` after the sixth `Pk_Path` string.

I tested the following command with `\zs`, I don't understand why this doesn't work:

```
:'<,'>s/\(\zsPk_Path\)\{6}+"\(.\{-}\)_dw2"/Pk_Path+\2_dw3"/g
```

It seems that I take the sixth occurrence of `Pk_Path` with `ns_dw2`, then add the `\2` pattern and the `ns_dw3` string.

### Update 1

I am close to the solution. For only the line:

`fold_path = [Pk_Path+"ns_up", Pk_Path+"ns_up2", Pk_Path+"fid", Pk_Path+"ns_dw", Pk_Path+"ns_dw2"]`

If I want to insert simultaneously `Pk_Path+"ns_up3"` after `Pk_Path+"ns_up2"` and `Pk_Path+"ns_dw3"` after `Pk_Path+"ns_dw2"`, I think following may be a solution closed to the wanted result:

(under vim), by doing:

`%s/\(Pk_Path+".\{-}_\)\([a-z]\{2}\)2"/\1\22,\1\23"/g`

i.e, I get the first pattern `\1` corresponding to `Pk_Path+"ns_`and second pattern which represents `up`or `dw` and I add to it the number `2`. So Finally, I replace them by for example the current `Pk_Path+"ns_up2"` by `Pk_Path+"ns_up2"` plus `Pk_Path+"ns_up2"`,`Pk_Path+"ns_up3"` (I was doing this by the part : `\1\22",\1\23"`

but unfortunately, I obtain:

```
fold_path = [Pk_Path+"ns_up", Pk_Path+"ns_up",Pk_Path+"ns_up", Pk_Path+"ns_up3", Pk_Path+"fid", Pk_Path+"ns_dw", Pk_Path+"ns_dw",Pk_Path+"fid", Pk_Path+"ns_dw", Pk_Path+"ns_dw3"]
```

As you can see, `Pk_Path+"ns_up2"` has disappeared and `Pk_Path+"ns_up"` like `Pk_Path+"fid"` appears 2 times.

Is it possible to use `\1\22, \1\23` in order to insert `\1\23` after `\1\22`. In order words, I would like to insert `\1\23` after `\1\22`.

Where is my mistake?

### Update 2

Here's the right command that I have been searching from the original post:

1. Expression to process (input) :

   fold_path = [Pk_Path+"ns_up", Pk_Path+"ns_up2", Pk_Path+"fid", Pk_Path+"ns_dw", Pk_Path+"ns_dw2"]
2. Command applied :

   :%s/(Pk_Path+"[a-z]{2}_[a-z]{2})(2)"/\1\2, \13"/g
3. Result (output) :

`fold_path = [Pk_Path+"ns_up", Pk_Path+"ns_up2, Pk_Path+"ns_up3", Pk_Path+"fid", Pk_Path+"ns_dw", Pk_Path+"ns_dw2, Pk_Path+"ns_dw3"]`

Comment: To replace Nth occurrence you could use: `sed 's/pattern/replacement/N' input_file`. Replace  `N` with an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I am not sure if this is what you are searching but here is my try:

```
:%s/\(Pk_Path+".\{-}",\=\s\=\)\{5}\zs\ze.*/, Pk_Path+"ns_dw3"/g
```

But if it is this that you are trying to achieve a simple search and then using `5n` (in a macro or so) may be an easier solution. A replace may not be the best way to insert new text.

**Update:**
I really am unsure what you want to achieve but to just solve the case you put in your update, it is a rather simple case of a regex:

```
%s/\(.*Pk_Path+"ns_up2"\)\(.*Pk_Path+"ns_dw2"\)\(.*\)/\1, Pk_Path+"ns_up3"\2, Pk_Path+"ns_dw3"\3
```

Breakdown:

```
\(.*Pk_Path+"ns_up2"\) " Capture everything up to "ns_up2" into group 1 
\(.*Pk_Path+"ns_dw2"\) " Capture from "ns_up2" to "ns_dw2" into group 2
\(.*\)                 " Capture the rest into group 3
```

Then it is just a matter of inserting your strings between group 1 and 2 and between group 2 and 3

Comment: @DokstirOSwaldo : Could you take a look please at my **UPDATE1** ? I am closed to the fixing with my own attempt.

Comment: Thanks, is there away to change only one or two patterns and keep the rest of line to modify unchanged. This is what I wanted to do initially like in this line : `text1, pattern1, text2, pattern2' which could be replaced by "text1, pattern1 pattern1_2, text2, pattern2, pattern2_2"`, ie insert `pattern1_2` after `pattern1` and `pattern2_2` after `pattern2`, all of this in the same time ?

Comment: I do not understand your request. have you tried my updated solution? This only inserts two parts into the text and leaves the rest unchanged.

Comment: The goal was to apply your solution but with a generic way about the `2`and `3` index for the word `Pk_Path+"ns_up` and `Pk_Path+"ns_dw`. Ideally, this would great to treat these words like a pattern and add then  index `3`instead of `2`: I don't know if it is possible in only one time, first for `Pk_Path+"ns_up2`, add `Pk_Path+"ns_up3` and same for `Pk_Path+"ns_dw2`. So  for this, I have to only capture `Pk_Path+"ns_up` and `Pk_Path+"ns_dw`. I hope you understand since it is a little bit tricky

Comment: it is possible, you could use a construct arround `\=Sum(submatch(0))` but a regex is not really the way to go, it may be easier to search for a pattern, than record a macro on one line.

Answer (score 2):

The `:substitute` command has an optional `[count]` argument; unfortunately, it just limits replacement to a number of *lines*, and does **not** count matches.

The only built-in option is supplying the `c`onfirm flag, and answer the prompts with `nnnnnl` to just replace the 6th match.

Alternatively, you can implement the counting inside the pattern, by matching the preceding elements with a `\%(...\)\{5}`, and then starting the actual match with [`:help /\zs`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Czs). But that's really cumbersome to write, and you need to duplicate the pattern (e.g. `\%(foo\)\{5}\zsfoo`).

My [PatternsOnText plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4602) has (among others) a `:SubstituteSelected` variant where you can directly specify the count (as `2,5` or `3-5` or even repeating `y3nyyn` answers).

Comment: Thanks, I tried another command which should be almost the solution : `:'<,'>s/, \(Pk_Path\zs\)\{6}+\(.\{-}\)_dw2"/\1\2_dw2", \1+\2_dw3"/g` . Indeed, I saw that `\(PATTERN\zc\)\{6}` should consider the 6th pattern on the line ..... but I may misunderstand the `\zc` option with the 6 th occurence `\{6}` : Any remark about this new replace command ? Regards

Comment: You're right, that's an alternative; I've added that to my answer, along with its downsides. You've meant `\zs` (_match start_); usually it's writtten behind the capture group, not at the end of the repeated capture.

Comment: A little bit tricky with `\zc`: I tried the following command, without success into vim with selected text  : `<,'>s/, \%(Pk_Path\)\{6}\zsPk_Path+\(.\{-}\)\{6}_dw2"/\1+\2_dw2", Pk_Path+\2_dw3"/g` : could you see what's wrong ? thanks

Comment: Superficially, that looks fine. I hope your struggles convince you to try some of the alternatives; you don't want to assemble and debug these monster expressions on a regular basis. (I would be fine if you develop a mapping that you'll frequently reuse.)

Comment: I admit that is a little complicated. By the way, what does percent symbol`%`do in the expression : `\%(foo\){5}`that you indicated in your answer above ??

Comment: `\%(` makes the `\(` non-capturing, so you cannot refer back to it via `\1`. Insignificantly more efficient, but helps if you actually need to do capturing in your pattern.

Comment: To better understand, which command have I got to do to get the 5th occurence of `Pk_Path `in the string : `fold_path = [Pk_Path+"ns_up", Pk_Path+"ns_up2", Pk_Path+"fid", Pk_Path+"ns_dw", Pk_Path+"ns_dw2"]`, Imean that I would like to capture the `Pk_Path+"ns_dw2"` pattern to add after it another string ?

Comment: I would like to start with a simple example to capture the Nth occurence a of a pattern and then, to add just after this occurence another string (`OTHERSTRING`) by doing `\1OTHERSTRING/g`

Comment: Could you take a look please at my **UPDATE1** ? I am closed to the fixing with my own attempt.

Comment: The fact that you're still struggling with the regexp is the best argument for a different solution, like my plugin's `:SubstituteSelected` command (have you tried it already?) Doing this with regexp matching may be fine for simple cases, but yours is anything but.